# How to combine two lists to plot coordinate pairs with one of the list having empty cells?

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the following lists:

[image: Lists]

How do I combine the two lists in order to plot points while ignoring the pairs where there is empty cells?. An example would be to get {0, 0.01}, {0, 0.03}, {0.127, 0},{0.285,1},{0.491,3},{0.865,10},(here is ignored the empty cell,10 pair),{0.951,30}.....etc.

Edit 1: Here's the list in mathematica form

```
{{0., 0.01}, {0., 0.03}, {0.12702, 0.1}, {0.284862, 0.3}, {0.330209, 
  1.}, {0.490592, 3.}, {0.864811, 10.}, {"", 10.}, {"", 
  10.}, {0.951112, 30.}, {"", 30.}, {"", 30.}, {0.924481, 100.}, {"", 
  100.}, {"", 100.}, {1.02702, 300.}, {"", 300.}, {"", 
  300.}, {1.12306, 1000.}, {"", 1000.}, {"", 1000.}, {1.061, 
  3000.}, {1.08021, 10000.}}
```

Edit 2: I tried Partition[Riffle[x,y],2] but this still pairs the empty cells and does not ignore them.

Comment: Please, always provide valid _Mathematica_ code in copyable form.

Comment: Thank you! I haved added the list in Mathematica form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
list = {{0., 0.01}, {0., 0.03}, {0.12702, 0.1}, {0.284862, 
    0.3}, {0.330209, 1.}, {0.490592, 3.}, {0.864811, 10.}, {"", 
    10.}, {"", 10.}, {0.951112, 30.}, {"", 30.}, {"", 30.}, {0.924481,
     100.}, {"", 100.}, {"", 100.}, {1.02702, 300.}, {"", 300.}, {"", 
    300.}, {1.12306, 1000.}, {"", 1000.}, {"", 1000.}, {1.061, 
    3000.}, {1.08021, 10000.}};
DeleteCases[list, {"", _}]
```

It might be helpful for plotting to have the data ordered by the first entry. You can to this as follows:

```
SortBy[DeleteCases[list, {"", _}], First]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.01}, {0., 0.03}, {0.12702, 0.1}, {0.284862, 0.3}, {0.330209, 1.}, {0.490592, 3.}, {0.864811, 10.}, {0.951112, 30.}, {0.924481, 100.}, {1.02702, 300.}, {1.12306, 1000.}, {1.061, 3000.}, {1.08021, 10000.}}
> ```

Comment: Yes, thank you!. If you don't mind. Let's say that instead of blanket or empty cells, I had the number "7". Is there any way to use the same code to pair everything, except that the cells that contain the number 7?. Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried to replace `""` by `"7"`? Btw., I expect that you read the documentation of each now symbol in the post. The point of my post was to show you that the command `DeleteCases` exists. I can cook a meal for you, but you have t eat it yourself...

Comment: Hi Henrik. Yes, I have and it does not work. That's why I am asking. Anyways, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to replace a `"7"`, `7`, `"7."`, or `7.`? These are indeed four different things, and the floating point `7.` is the hardest to come by...

Comment: Henry, I would like the number 7. I thought I would also be similar to your code replacing "" but it seems harder than that.