# Importing data ignoring empty cells

Tags: list-manipulation, import, filtering

If a have the following data (see the picture and the data below)

```
data={{"x-axis", "y-axis"}, {0.01, 0.}, {0.03, 0.}, {0.1, 0.12702}, {0.3, 
  0.284862}, {1., 0.330209}, {3., 0.490592}, {10., 0.864811}, {10., 
  ""}, {10., ""}, {30., 0.951112}, {30., ""}, {30., ""}, {100., 
  0.924481}, {100., ""}, {100., ""}, {300., 1.02702}, {300., 
  ""}, {300., ""}, {1000., 1.12306}, {1000., ""}, {1000., ""}, {3000.,
   1.061}, {10000., 1.08021}}
```

[image: Data]

how can I import all the data in order but ignoring the pairs that have empty cells (those in red in the picture). In other words, I would like to obtain the following for imported values:

```
   importedvalues= {0.01, 0.}, {0.03, 0.}, {0.1, 0.12702}, {0.3, 
          0.284862}, {1., 0.330209}, {3., 0.490592}, {10., 0.864811},{30., 0.951112},{100.,0.924481},{300., 1.02702},{1000., 1.12306},{3000.,1.061}, {10000., 1.08021}}
```

I tried using

```
importedvalues = Extract[Import["file.xlsx"], 
   1][[2 ;; 24, {1, 2}]]
```

but this give me all the pairs, including the empty cells.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `DeleteCases[data, {_?NumberQ, ""}]`?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!. I am very new to Mathematica and I was not aware of how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: J.M sorry. I tried the code again and it does not seem to work sometimes giving a list like {1,2,,3,4,,5,,6....etc}. I think this code only works when it contains Import or Export, correct?. Will this work for instance if I have a list with empty values such as {0.,0.,0.12702,0.284862,0.330209,0.490592,0.864811,,,0.951112,,,0.924481,,,1.02702,,,1.12306,,,1.061,1.08021}, where I want to get rid of of the empty parts of the list?

Comment: Isn’t this pretty much the same question you asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/220473/27951) only three hours ago?

Comment: What I wrote was only intended for lists like your `data`, where the lists you want to remove (hence the use of `DeleteCases[]`) have the null string (`""`) as the second component (`{_?NumberQ, ""}`). You need to do something else for that new list.